# Datediff function in T-sql

Tags: t-sql

What will be the output the following call:

```
 DATEDIFF(wk,14,GET DATE())
```

`14` indicates a date or it indicates 2 weeks difference?

Comment: `DATEDIFF` expects two _dates_ as the 2nd and 3rd parameters AFAIK.  So, what you wrote doesn't make much sense, even if it would run.

Comment: DATEDIFF(wk,14,GETDATE()

Comment: What does this 14 mean?

Comment: Do you not have access to MSDN for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

so **14** should indicate **start date**. Check [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples), because adding just 14 doesn't make sense, it should be a date, e.g.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(week, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
```

Answer (score 0):

As svkaka wrote in his answer, the `DATEDIFF` function expects a datepart, start date and end date - However, your code supplies it with an `int` as it's second argument.
In such cases, SQL Server will implicitly convert the `int` to `DateTime`, so

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(wk, 14, GetDate())
```

is in fact

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(wk, '1900-01-15', GetDate())
```

Since casting 14 to DateTime will result with that date.
Please note, however, that none of the other Date/Time data types can be directly converted from an int.

This is the basis of a technique that was used in older versions of SQL Server to truncate parts of a DateTime value.
For instance, if you wanted to truncate the time part in 2005 version, you would do this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) -- 0 meaning January 1st 1900
```

(in 2008 you would simply cast to `date`).

However, in the newer versions of SQL Server (in fact, since 2012 introduced `datefromparts` and it's sibling functions) this technique is no longer needed.